# How to make express Node.JS reply a request during heavy workload?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm creating an nodejs web processor. I's is processing time that takes ~ 1 minute. I `POST` to my server and get status by using `GET`

this is my simplified code

```
// Configure Express
const app = express();
app.listen(8080);

// Console
app.post('/clean', async function(req, res, next) {
  
    // start proccess
    let result = await worker.process(data);

    // Send result when finish
    res.send(result);
});

// reply with when asked
app.get('/clean', async function(req, res, next) {
    res.send(worker.status);
});
```

The problem is. The server is working so hard in the `POST /clean` process that `GET /clean` are not replied in time.

All `GET /clean` requests are replied after the worker finishes its task and free the processor to respond the request.

[image]

In other words. The application are unable to respond during workload.

How can I get around this situation?

Comment: What is `worker.process()`?  What is it doing?  Can you show us the code for it?  Is it in the same process as node.js or in another process?

Comment: worker.process takes the data ( a ~10 MB CSV file) parse to javascript object, do a lot of processes and them return the result. In the same node process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because node.js runs your Javascript as single threaded (only one piece of Javascript ever running at once) and does not time slice, as long as your `worker.process()` is running it's synchronous code, no other requests can be processed by your server.  This is why `worker.process()` has to finish before any of the http requests that arrived while it was running get serviced.  The node.js event loop is busy until `worker.process()` is done so it can't service any other events (like incoming http requests).

These are some of the ways to work around that:

1. Cluster your app with the built-in cluster module so that you have a bunch of processes that can either work on `worker.process()` code or handle incoming http requests.
2. When it's time to call `worker.process()`, fire up a new node.js process, run the processing there and communicate back the result with standard interprocess communication.  Then, your main node.js process stays reading to handle incoming http requests near instantly as they arrive.
3. Create a work queue of a group of additional node.js processes that run jobs that are put in the queue and configure these processes to be able to run your `worker.process()` code from the queue.  This is a variation of #2 that bounds the number of processes and serializes the work into a queue (better controlled than #2).
4. Rework the way `worker.process()` does its work so that it can do a few ms of work at a time, then return back to the message loop so other events can run (like incoming http requests) and then resume it's work afterwards for a few more ms at a time.  This usually requires building some sort of stateful object that can do a little bit of work at a time each time it is called, but is often a pain to program effectively.

Note that #1, #2 and #3 all require that the work be done in other processes.  That means that the `process.status()` will need to get the status from those other processes.  So, you will either need some sort of interprocess way of communicating with the other processes or you will need to store the status as you go in some storage that is accessible from all processes (such as redis) so it can just be retrieved from there.

Answer (score 1):

There's no working around the single-threaded nature of JS short of converting your service to a cluster of processes or to use something experimental like [Worker Threads](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/worker_threads.html).

If neither of these options work for you, you'll need to yield up the processing thread periodically to give other tasks the ability to work on things:

```
function workPart1() {
  // Do a bunch of stuff
  setTimeout(workPart2, 10); 
}
function workPart2() {
  // More stuff
  setTimeout(workPart3, 10); // etc. 
}
```